# How to convert a line to a list and read its elements: Python

Tags: python, list, element

I am reading from a file that looks like this:
Ikard Wynne Llp|[('209.163.183.92', '209.163.183.95')]

```
    Innovation Technologies Ltd|[('91.238.88.0', '91.238.91.255'), ('195.128.153.0', '195.128.153.255')]
    House Of Flowers|[('69.15.170.220', '69.15.170.223'), ('108.178.223.20', '108.178.223.23')]
    Hertitage Peak Charter School|[('66.81.93.192', '66.81.93.207')]
```

and I am willing to convert the part after '|' to a list and then read the tuples from the list. I am using this script to do that but I the script recognize each list as an element instead of each tuple. Does any body know how to fix that?

```
for line in g:
    org= line.split("|")[0]
    ranges = [line.split('|')[1]]
    for range in ranges:
    print (range)
```

output:

```
[('91.238.88.0', '91.238.91.255'), ('195.128.153.0', '195.128.153.255')]
[('69.15.170.220', '69.15.170.223'), ('108.178.223.20', '108.178.223.23')]
[('66.81.93.192', '66.81.93.207')]

        for ip in range:
        print (ip)
```

output:

```
[
(
'
9
1
.
1
9
5
.
1
7
2
.
0
'
,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "Innovation Technologies Ltd|[('91.238.88.0', '91.238.91.255'), ('195.128.153.0', '195.128.153.255')]"
>>> z = ast.literal_eval(s.split('|')[1])
>>> z
[('91.238.88.0', '91.238.91.255'), ('195.128.153.0', '195.128.153.255')]
>>> z[0]
('91.238.88.0', '91.238.91.255')
>>> z[0][1]
'91.238.91.255'
>>> type(z)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(z[0])
<type 'tuple'>
```

From the documentation:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or
>   node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and
>   None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.